# Should my class have a method for each file format, or should I delegate I/O to other, file-format-specific classes?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, dependencies, loose-coupling, cohesion

In a given domain, there can be multiple file formats representing similar objects or structures. For example, an object of type `Track` (meaning a sequence of geographical points) can be saved in .GPX, .KML, GeoJSON, WKT, ShapeFile, etc.

So, my class `Track` is supposed to read and save its data from files, which can be in different formats.

Question is:

> Should my class implement the methods to read from each file type (that is, "know about" them), or should it use other classes, where each class would contain logic to interact with implementation details of each file type? What is the standard practice?

The first option would be coded like this:

```
trackCollection.Add(Track.loadFromGPX(gpx_fname))
trackCollection.Add(Track.loadfromKML(kml_fname))
# ...and so on with other filetypes
```

while the second option would probably be:

```
trackCollection.Add(GpxReader.getTrack(gpx_fname))
trackCollection.Add(KmlReader.getTrack(kml_fname))
```

It seems to me that some characteristics involving Single Responsability Principle, Information Hiding, and interdependence between classes might make one approach better than the other, but I am not experienced enough to figure which one, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that each file type may need to be parsed with a completely different library and logic, I would certainly prefer the second method (separate classes).

I would only use a "loadFromXXX" method for supporting arguments with different datatypes or methods that will share a lot of code. For example, in C++, you might have `loadFromFile(std::ifstream& input)` and `loadFromString(std::string& str)`. `loadFromFile()` may end up parsing the file into a string and call `loadFromString` or it may parse the file line by line and just share some of the parse functions used in `loadFromString`.

In any case, it appears that the file formats you listed have very little in common and some (such as KML vs GeoJSON) require completely different parsers. As a result, there should be a separate "reader" or "parser" class for each file type. Otherwise you are bloating class `Track` and it will have very low cohesion. Separation of concerns would also suggest you split the parsing into another class.